# Why is an automatic migration being created for changes that are included in an explicit migration?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Scenario: both myself and a co-worker create explicit code first migrations. When trying to apply them, we encounter the "Pending Changes" error. I enabled automatic migrations and used the   -script parameter to see the sql statements. It's creating three migrations: mine, my co-workers, and then an automatic migration that consists of the same statements that my EXPLICIT migration included (obviously, the Insert statement for the migration history table is slightly different).

I'm at a loss. Why are my changes being viewed as pending, even though they are included in the explicit migration?

Comment: Though you're using explicit migrations, are you building them via `Add-Migration`? There may be metachanges that you may not see but the migration checksum is saying are different.

Comment: @BradChristie Yes, the migrations were added using the Add-Migration command from the console.